# ARM template to update keyvault property

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Could you please share a solution to update keyvault property publicNetworkAccess to disabled using ARM template. I have been trying alot but unable find the solution?

Thanks.

I have tried deploying a new keyvault and in same template update working whereas unable to update existing keyvault properties by retrieving existing property such as Access policies and sku to use same. Tried reference function also not working.
It would be helpful if anyone share a solution with an example.

Comment: Once look into the similar issue in [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/943297/unable-to-change-34publicnetworkaccess34-34disable.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Harshitha, gone through it but unable to understand the integration in ARM templates

PATCH  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/{cache}?api-version=2020-06-01
 {    "properties": {
        "publicNetworkAccess":"Disabled"
    }
 }

Answer (score 0):

To get an ARM template with the `publicNetworkAccess` property set to disabled, you can try to:

1. Create a Key Vault
2. Go to the Networking blade
3. Disable public access
4. Export the template to use and modify as needed.
   [image]

   ```
                "enabledForDeployment": true,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": true,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
                "enableSoftDelete": true,
                "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 7,
                "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
                "enablePurgeProtection": true,
                "vaultUri": "https://KeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
   ```

**Additional Link:**

[How to create an Azure key vault and vault access policy by using a Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vault-create-template?tabs=CLI)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @james, i have already tried this but no luck. And one scenario it's working in same template i.e., keyvault create using same keyvault name and update only publicNetworkAccess but accesspolicies and sku are updating as i don't have the parameters in my ARM template as per requirement. Actually through ARM template i have to update only "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled" without updating other values/ retrieve all the properties and update only publicNetworkAccess. Kindly share the solution for this issue.